# Angular2: anchor tag has no href link unless reloading page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a link defined in `navigation.component.html` as

```
<a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">
```

The `navigation` component is like

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-nav',
  templateUrl: 'app/layout/navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/layout/navigation.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavigationComponent {

}
```

The route config is in another component like

```
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-route-dispatcher',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/dispatcher/route-dispatcher.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavigationComponent]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
  },
])
```

It's corresponding template is like

```
<db2nav></db2nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem is that when I first load the page, the link in the `navigation.component` doesn't work, `<a>` has no `href` link at all. If I refresh this page, `<a>` has correct`href` link and it works well. How should I fix this to make it work since first load?

Comment: Could you provide full sample on plunker?

Comment: @kemsky probably not, the project has multiple components and directives

Comment: Did you set a base `href` in your `index.html`?

Comment: @PierreDuc Yeah, I did. `<base href="/">` inside the `<head>`